# Flyout IsPinned = False/True (MahApps)

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have 2 "problems" with flyouts in MahApps

1) When `IsPinned="False"` and `ExternalCloseButton="Left"`, two clicks are required to give focus to a control (textbox in this case), 1 to close flyout, and 1 to focus control. Is it possible that with a 1 click, close the flyout and focus on the control?

When "`IsPinned=True`", and a control has the focus, when the flyout automatically close, the control loses focus.

Thx!

```
<mahApps:MetroWindow x:Class="IsPinned.MainWindow"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:mahApps="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                     Title="MainWindow"
                     Height="350"
                     Width="525"
                     WindowTransitionsEnabled="False"
                     WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                     BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}">

    <mahApps:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
        <mahApps:FlyoutsControl>
            <mahApps:Flyout IsPinned="False"
                            Height="150"
                            Width="250"
                            IsOpen="True"
                            Position="Left"
                            ExternalCloseButton="Left"
                            AutoCloseInterval="6000"
                            IsAutoCloseEnabled="True">
                <mahApps:Flyout.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="Test"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </mahApps:Flyout.HeaderTemplate>

            </mahApps:Flyout>
        </mahApps:FlyoutsControl>
    </mahApps:MetroWindow.Flyouts>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Margin="5"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

</mahApps:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: Can you create two issues on github repository for this? Thx!

Comment: @punker76 Hi! yes check this https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2744. Thx!